# Why Include variable declaration in Javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In Jon Duckett's "Javascript and Jquery", he often uses a for loop like below. He explains that this variable actually builds to as many numbers are as found for the loop. What I don't understand is if youre setting the `variable = 0` every time it runs, how can it accumulate higher numbers? Furthermore, why would you want this in your loop, shouldnt you specify it outside the loop instead so it can accumulate to a higher number instead of resetting to 0 each time?

```
if (hotItems.length > 0) {
    for (var i=0; i<hotItems.length; i++) {
        hotItems[i].className = 'cool';
    }
}
```

Comment: No *good* reason except to avoid putting it in the global scope, the issue is that if it's not at the top of whatever function the code appears in, the variable is hoisted, which can lead to unexpected results at times.

Comment: You're not setting it each time, btw; it's an initialization that occurs before the loop starts executing.

Comment: In addition to Dave Newton and Scimonster.. There is a good reason to _not_ define it outside. You could simply forget to reset that i if you used it somewhere else. Because of that the var 'i = 0;' or even 'i = 0;' and definitely not 'i;' if you do not have a very good reason for it.

Comment: Thanks Dave/Alex definitely helpful also!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole concept of a `for` loop is kind of like a shortcut for a `while` loop. You're mentally parsing this the wrong way. Using a `while` loop, this would be:

```
var i=0;
while (i<hotItems.length) {
hotItems[i].className = 'cool';
i++;
}
```

Read the `for` loop as being three parts: The first goes before the loop, the second is the condition, and the third goes at the end of each iteration.

So, it is not being set each time. Only once.

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, an initial statement that is non-conditional will always be run only once, despite the conditional after it being called repeatedly?

Comment: Thanks for your lightning fast response in aid of my path to javascript enlightenment!